# Dominant 7th #11 vs ♭5

Tags: chords

Why do people always say dominant 7th ♯11 and ♭5 are the same because obviously  they aren't. A flat 5 means the fifth is flat and natural 4th is still present and vice versa for ♯11. A dominant 7th flat five would have a flat 5 in its major triad vs sharp 11 which would be an altered upper chordtone.

Comment: First I’d like to say to the downvoter if you have a problem with the question why not post a comment about it instead? This is a new user after all. Regarding the question, you may have been downvoted because your question is about other people’s opinions of a musical topic rather than about the topic itself. Regardless of that my personal experience is that musicians who truly know their theory and harmony know there is a difference between the two.

Comment: In my answer I‘ve overlooked the *dominant* in your  question. Could you tell us a) which instrument you‘re playing and give me an example of a piece with this chord V#11?

Comment: There are a lot of different things that people could be trying to express with these notations. In jazz, these symbols don't really indicate chord voicings, they represent functions and scales. For example, 7♭5 could be used when the composer intends a wholetone scale, and you could find that out by studying the melody or by listening to recordings. There are not definitive absolute rules that tell you what voicing to play given a certain chord symbol. It depends on style and context. These notations could just be intended to warn the piano player about a melody note that could clash.

Answer (score 5):

Do 'peope always say'? Not where I am!

Yes, flat 5 means flat 5 (diminished fifth in reality), but the natural 4th (perfect fourth in reality) is never present. For ♯11, that note will be the augmented eleventh (not a ♯4, which clashes with the M3 and P5) and becaause the number is greater than 7, a 7th must be included as well.

7♭5 *will* have a diminished fifth *and* a minor seventh, whereas a ♯11 chord will have a major triad, a minor seventh and an augmented eleventh. Not quite the same **voicings**.

Answer (score 2):

Chord notation is highly context sensitive. In a chart, if you see `7b5` or `7#11`, the only thing you can know for sure is that the chord *does* contain the scale degrees `1`, `3`, `b5`/`#4`, and `b7`. However, those four notes alone aren't enough to specify which mode should be used. Over a so-called `7b5` chord, you might choose to play the [half-whole diminished scale](https://www.keyboardmag.com/lessons/discover-the-power-of-the-dominant-diminished-scale) or [lydian dominant scale](http://www.simplifyingtheory.com/lydian-dominant-mode-and-hexatonic-scale/), both of which include natural 5ths. Alternatively, you could choose to play the [whole-tone scale](https://www.musikalessons.com/blog/2016/07/whole-tone-scale/) or the [altered dominant scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altered_scale), which have a `#5` (or `b6`) instead. In practice, the chord symbol `7b5` doesn't necessarily rule out the presence of the natural 5th, nor does it necessarily mean something different from `7#11`.  (Recall that the 5th is consider the "weakest" chord tone, so in a `7#11` voicing, an accompanist is likely to substitute the ♯11 for the 5 rather than play both.)

To specify the exact mode without ambiguity, the composer needs to choose a more specific chord symbol: `7alt` implies the altered scale, `13b9` implies the diminished scale, and `+9` implies a whole-tone scale. An exercise for you: What chord symbol would you use to "guarantee" that the soloist will use the lydian dominant scale?

There are purists who argue that the chord symbols with sharps in them should be reserved for the diminished scale while flats should indicate the altered scale—which is to say that the chord symbol `7b5` cannot refer to a chord with a natural 5th in it. It would certainly be helpful to beginners if people were consistent with their notation, but composers tend to develop individual styles while leaning on musicians' intuition about which modes should go where. That means that some people will, in fact, write `7b5` when the melody uses the diminished scale and contains a natural 5th. Accompanists are expected to keep their "ears open" in situations like this rather than assume that they can base their voicings on the altered scale. Likewise, if the soloist sees `7#11` and hears the accompanist play a voicing based on the whole-tone scale, they should adjust their playing to match.

So, to someone learning chord symbols at an intermediate level (which is where you seem to be), I would recommend thinking of each chord symbol as not a prescription for a particular mode, but a set of notes that could fit into many modes. The mode that you ultimately base your playing on is determined not just by the chord symbol, but by the context and the musical cues you receive from your bandmates.

Comment: Suggest you read the question carefully! There's no mention of what scale notes ought to be played - only asking about chord names.

Comment: The ambiguity applies when naming chords, too: If I write the notes C, E, F#, and Bb on a staff, many musicians will call this `C7b5` even though it is spelled with a #4. You can argue that those musicians are wrong, but the poster is asking why they would say this.

Answer (score 0):

In notation of Blues you always find ♭5 and ♯11 equivalent. Usually both notes are resolved up to the perfect fifth or down to the fourth, as chromatic approaches or passing tones.

Logical is ♯11 when leading up, and ♭5 when passing down. But the readability is preceding the theory **in  newer notation.**

Comment: I see no contrast between your last two sentences. To make your music readable (i.e. avoid making it needlessly hard to read), spell the notes correctly. Theory explains why the spelling is what it is. In this context, theory and readability go together -- neither has to take precedence over the other.

Comment: What I mean to say: in popmusic and especially in blues - where the b5 and #11 are actually blue notes and as such bent tones - the notation is ignoring the chord theory that OP is relying on. I think readability you mean is concerning the chord ciphers for guitarists or pianists. I was referring to the notation of the notes in a staff for keyboards. And there the editors ignore usually the theory - today!